# why don't getValue(nameClass ::class.java) work for me in Kotlin with Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
val data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val refB = data.getReference("branches")
refB.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for(n in snapshot.children){
            val branch = n.getValue(Branch::class.java)
            listB.add(branch!!)
        }
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    }
})
```

[image]

my class Branch

```
class Branch(var id: String?, var nStudents: String, var nTeachers: String, var name:String) {
}
```

I can't read the data one sentence means Object,
But I can read the data each value by itself.

Comment: 1) The class you shared is named `Manager`, but you're using `Branch` in the first snippet. 2) The property names need to exactly match those in the database, so `name` instead of `fname`, etc.

Comment: I just corrected the question and the problem is still there

Comment: `id` and `name` should work, but `nStudents` <> `nstudents` as the matching is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your custom class:

1. As Frank pointed out in a comment, `nStudents` and `nTeachers` won't map correctly due to case sensitivity.
2. It seems like your class has no empty constructor (or [default arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments)) which is required for the database to properly deserialize the data, as detailed in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write).
3. The data types don't seem to match: You've declared `nstudents` and `nteachers` as `String`, but I see it as numbers in your database, so you should probably use an `Int` or `Long`.

With all that said, your updated class should look like this:

```kotlin
class Branch(
    var id: String? = null,
    var nstudents: Int = 0,
    var nteachers: Int = 0,
    var name: String = ""
) {
    // ...
}
```

And if the only purpose of this class is to hold data, you can turn it into a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html):

```kotlin
data class Branch(
    var id: String? = null,
    var nstudents: Int = 0,
    var nteachers: Int = 0,
    var name: String = ""
)
```

Comment: thanks Rosário Pereira Fernandes 